# "Height of cube" = Area of projection to plane

Tags: euclidean-geometry, projection

Let a unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that one of its vertices is on the $x-y$ plane, and all other vertices have a positive $z$-coordinate.

I need to show that the height of the cube - namely the highest $z$-coordinate over the points of the cube, is given by the area of its projected area on the $x-y$ plane.

I did get that $z_{\rm max}=|\cos{(\alpha)}|+|\cos{(\beta)}|+|\cos{(\gamma)}|$, which is the projected areas of three non parallel faces of the cube. But what about the other three? is there a way to show that their projection will necessarily fall on the projection of the first three faces?

Comment: Draw a vertical line passing through the cube. It will necessarily pass through two faces of the cube, unless it passes right through one of its edges. Only the lower point will then contribute to the projection, as the point above it is obstructed by atleast the lower point.

Comment: I agree, and it makes sense. I was wondering if I could find a more "rigorous" way of prooving this fact.